# Proxy Error - After changed hosting

Tags: proxy, web-hosting

I just changed from a free hosting to hosting24 - I have never changed a hosting before - and I just transfered all the files as they were, I created a database and imported all the tables from the previous database and now I get "proxy error" when I try to load the site. No other information whatsoever.

Anybody know what I can do?

Comment: please share more details

Comment: Ι don't know what to say, I basically just changed the hosting from 000webhost to hosting24 and I transfered all the files from pubic_html to public_html and I made a database to which I imported all the tables I had.

Comment: did you verify the hosting configurations in old and new

Comment: Probably not, how would I do that?

Comment: Check your webserver error log for hints. I also suggest asking your host for assistance as this might be related to some configuration on their end.

Comment: Have you tried following
1) Browse your website in alternate browser on your computer. If you do not have an alternative web browser then restart the one you were using

2) Clear the web browser’s cache and launch your website.

3) Restart your computer and network device you are using to access Internet. If above does not fix your issue, contact your ISP and host.